# Data binding to jsTree

Tags: javascript, jquery, data-binding, jstree

What I'm looking to do is bind some dynamic data to a jsTree (i.e. a tree component from [this library](http://www.jstree.com/)) tree using a JS framework. I'm incidentally using [vue.js](http://vuejs.org/) but this problem is totally framework independent. At the moment it looks like jsTree only supports setting the tree data on initialization, i.e. when you call `$().jstree()`, which is not what I want, as my data will change over time, and I want this to be reflected in the tree itself.

The most obvious way, binding to HTML and then creating jsTree on these elements doesn't work because jsTree removes the original HTML from the DOM when it initializes:

```
<div id="jsTree">
    <!--This is all destroyed :( -->
    <ul>
        <li v-repeat="nodes"> {{$value}} </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

However if you just play with the DOM and manually add nodes to the tree *after* it has initialized, it looks fine. But you can't bind data to the DOM after the page has been compiled by the framework (without difficulty).

So how can jsTree be used with data binding?

Answer (score 0):

Since I found no existing solutions, I made two of my own.

Firstly is [jsTreeBind](https://github.com/TMiguelT/jsTreeBind). It does exactly what I wanted when I made this post. You create a hidden tree of standard HTML elements with DOM templating (`<div>s` for example), and then the plugin converts this tree into a jsTree, updating on the fly to keep up with DOM updates.

**However** I eventually realized that this isn't actually a very good solution, since scope data was being duplicated 4 times. If you think about the original scope data used to generate the jsTree, this data was being stored once in the framework's scope (1), once in the DOM view it's bound to (2), once in the jsTree json data (3), and once in the jsTree DOM (4).

So in light of this, I made **[Botany](https://github.com/TMiguelT/botany)**, a library that makes tree views (like jsTree), but *declaratively*, meaning that you just bind data to the DOM, and apply the `.botany` class, and it suddenly looks like a tree. The data doesn't go through a convoluted series of transforms, and will update automatically because that's how CSS works. The project isn't totally finished, but I recommend having a look, and helping out with suggestions or contributions if you can!

Answer (score 0):

I have implented things in angularjs Using $templateRequest, you can load a template by it’s URL without having to embed it into your HTML page. If the template is already loaded, for example, on button click in Angularjs Controller

```
app.controller('testCtrl', function($scope, $templateRequest, $sce, $compile){

   $scope.MakeTemplateToJsTree = function () {

         var templateUrl = $sce.getTrustedResourceUrl('Security/UlListTemp');

         $templateRequest(templateUrl).then(function (template) {

             $compile($("#boxTree").html(template).contents())($scope);

         }, function () {
       
        });

      // this NodeList array will bind to ng-repeat
       $scope.NodeList = [];
   


       setTimeout(function () {
            $('#jstree_demo_div').jstree();
        }, 300)

    }
 });
```

//#jstree_demo_div is in UlListTemp a partial view in asp.net MVC, which have complete functionality like ng-repeat
And i am sharing my partial view as template "_UlListTemp.chtml"

```
<div id="jstree_demo_div">
   <ul class="sidebar-menu">
      <li class="treeview" ng-repeat="n in NodeList" id="li{{n.Id}}">
        <a href="#">
            <span>{{n.ModuleName}}</span>
        </a>
        <ul class="treeview-menu">
            <li ng-repeat="p in n.ProgramList">
                <a>
                            <span>{{p.ApplicationName}}</span>
                </a>
            </li>

        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```